# Normal map + shading smooth weird

Tags: shaders, normal-map, smooth

I have a problem that never happened to me before, will explain it in a simple way :

I start a new scene, I remove the basic elements as I always do.
I put a new cube + surface modifier subdivision + cast (I apply the modifiers).
Then I smooth and in classic object mode no worries, I decide to take a normal map in texture mode as done a lot of times before.
So I'm in material preview mode, I paint the normal map and this is where it starts when I then connect the normal map with a normal map node so that it connects correctly with the principled BSDF, still in material preview mode, all sides appear.
I've tried all the possible solutions, nothing works.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here a pics of the new scene i tried to understand what happened.

[image]

Here the original scene where the problem start without understanding why :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WHIM.jpg)
[image]
[image]

---

The last pics to help you to see:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Scroll down in your material settings for that material and see what _Blend Mode_ it's using. If it's anything other than _Opaque_ try enabling/disabling _Backface Culling_ and/or _Show Backface_.

Comment: I looked, but I hadn't touched anything here because it was really to test in a new scene.

Because the problem appeared in another scene where I worked.
I will show you with photo to make it more clear for you.

Comment: Where did you get the normal texture from? There are more than one convention for normal maps, usually what differs is the green channel, it may have to be inverted.

Comment: https://victorkarp.com/inverting-a-normal-map-in-blender/#:~:text=Y%2B%20and%20Y%2D%20normal%20maps&text=If%20you%20use%20a%20Y,done%20in%20Blender's%20shader%20editor.

In this link he explains what I mean about the green channel, and how to fix it.

Comment: Hello, the normal map i used is one i did myself with photoshop like i did before for my second pokeball, and no problem with, but i tried to invert the green channel and nothing change, the same problem is still here, the normal map plugged and the shading smooth stay weird even in a totally new scene. thank you for sharing but yes nothing for the moment. i really dont understand why this happened, and yes only appeared when i plugged normal map to the object.

Comment: Hello again, i had downloaded the newest version of blender, and its the same nothing change, as soon as I want to connect a normal map, and I go to material preview, the smooth shading is completely messed up and makes all the faces appear and, well, I absolutely don't understand and it's a test done on a new scene.

Comment: Can you include in the question a screenshot of the normal map texture itself?

Comment: This is only occurring with a specific texture, right?

Comment: hello again, nope this is with some specific normal i did myself pwith photoshop, but the problem i had here is ununderstanding for me cause i did this bunch of time bdefore et without this issues, and to answer you i cant send more pictures cause of my reputation for the moment . to be clear, the normal map you can saw on the pics number 6 is made in the same way i did before, and when i use it now the same problem is still here :/ .

Comment: i post the normal map i want to use here

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but seeing your texture I can see what the problem is right away.
I wrote an answer. If it satisfies your question please upvote it and mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your normal map has a white background.

[image]

White means all the channels (red, green and blue) are at 1 (or 100%). So the shader is taking the geometry normals and rotating it in weird ways to get the textured normal. This is why the normals are messed up when you use this texture. The background of a normal texture for blender should be this blueish purple color:

[image]

(I think the RGB values are 0.5, 0.5, 1, if I'm not mistaken)
The values in this color represent unchanged normals. In the places where the texture has this color, the geometry normals are unchanged. That's what you want in the background of your skull normal texture.

This probably happened because you used a png with transparent background to create the normal texture, and the background was still the default white background in photoshop.
Try doing it again, but merge the skull png with the background before creating the normal map, you'll notice the background will be purple instead of white.